# Optimize Jade Wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, pug, templating

I'm looking to print a div drawn from a series of objects. I can achieve this by using the pipe syntax below.

```
each i, key in faq
    if (key == 0)
        | <div class="list-group dropdown">
        |   <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        |       <strong>#{faq[key].section}</strong>
        |   </h6>
        |   <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>

    else if (faq[key].section != faq[key-1].section)
        | </div>
        | <div class="list-group dropdown">
        |   <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        |       <strong>#{faq[key].section}</strong>
        |   </h6>
        |   <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>

    else
        |   <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>

    if (key == faq.length)
        | </div>
```

HOWEVER I would like to achieve this without pipe syntax. I was wondering if that is possible?

I'm basically looking for something like this

```
each i, key in faq
    if (key == 0 || faq[key].section != faq[key-1].section)
        h6.list-title(data-toggle="dropdown")
            strong #{faq[key].section}
    else
            strong #{faq[key].section}
```

but that prints something alike to

```
<div class="list-group ">
    <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>#{faq[key].section}</strong>
    </h6>
    <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>
</div>
<a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>
```

when I want it to be

```
<div class="list-group ">
    <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>#{faq[key].section}</strong>
    </h6>
    <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>
    <a class="list-group-item">#{faq[key].question}</a>
</div>
```

expanded...

```
<div class="list-group ">
    <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>Desktop FAQ</strong>
    </h6>
    <a class="list-group-item">Who licenses the fonts? The designer or the company?</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group ">
    <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>Licensing</strong>
    </h6>
    <a class="list-group-item">Who licenses the fonts?</a>
    <a class="list-group-item">Who wants to licenses the fonts?</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group ">
    <h6 class="list-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>Installation</strong>
    </h6>
    <a class="list-group-item">Installation question 1</a>  
    <a class="list-group-item">Inst. Q 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if-else logic is overly complicated and doesn't follow DRY principles. Your if-else only really need to decide three things:

1. Include the `</div>` at the start?
2. Include the middle section? (contents of `if (key == 0)`)
3. Include the `</div>` at the end? (The logic here is good)

With the code as it is, you can't remove the pipes completely. The reason being that Jade automatically handles opening and closing tags for you. However, you are trying to handle it yourself, so you need to override Jade here. However, unless you have a good reason to believe the tags may be mismatched, you shouldn't be bothering with it. I'm presuming that you do, since you are bothering.

The upside is that you only really need them for the lines where you may have troubles with mismatches between opening and closing tags. Therefore you only need it for the lines with `</div>` and maybe the lines with `<div>`.

---

The code should look something like this (recommend better variable names for `condA` and `condB`)

```
each i, key in faq
    - condA = (key == 0)
    - condB = (faq[key].section != faq[key-1].section)

    if (not condA and condB)
        | </div>
    if (condA or condB)
        | <div class="list-group dropdown">
        h6.list-title(data-toggle='dropdown')
            strong #{faq[key].section}
    a.list-group-item #{faq[key].question}

    if (key == faq.length)
        | </div>
```

You can probably do it completely without the pipes, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly.

---

That being said, it sounds like that the data structure your currently using is insufficient for the task. Seems like you should be using a 2D structure in the format: `faq[topic][question#] = question` instead. The data structure in your example would look like this:

```
faq = {
    "Desktop FAQ": {
        "1": "Who licenses the fonts? The designer or the company?"
    },
    "Licensing": {
        "1": "Who licenses the fonts?",
        "2": "Who wants to licenses the fonts?"
    },
    "Installation": {
        "1": "Installation question 1",
        "2": "Inst. Q 2"
    }
}
```

Here the code with the example `faq` data, which works in the [online demo for Jade](http://jade-lang.com/), faq is compacted to a single line as defining JS objects on multiple lines doesn't seem to work well in Jade (or at least the online demo).

```
- faq={"Desktop FAQ":{1:"Who licenses the fonts? The designer or the company?"},"Licensing":{1:"Who licenses the fonts?",2:"Who wants to licenses the fonts?"},"Installation":{1:"Installation question 1",2:"Inst. Q 2"}}

for questions, topic in faq
    .list-group.dropdown
        h6.list-title(data-toggle='dropdown')
            strong #{topic}
        for question in questions
            a.list-group-item #{question}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following.. do you think you could revise your answer with example solution code?

Comment: @QuinnKeaveney Updated with a version of what I had in mind, as well as one for a suggested change in the data structure to simply the code. Though you may want to add a check for topics without questions and display something other than a blank there. Also [HTML2Jade](http://www.html2jade.org/) combined with the online demo is rather helpful.